# Python: type checking of complex returned values

Tags: python, typechecking

I am writing a framework that calls into code written by other people (the framework plays Monopoly and calls into player AIs). The AIs tell the framework what to do in the return values of function calls.

I would like to check the types of the return values to make sure that they won't blow up my framework code.

For example:

```
instructions = player.sell_houses()
# Process the instructions...
```

In this example I am expecting the player to return a list of tuples, such as:

```
[(Square.BOW_STREET, 2), (Square.MARLBOROUGH_STREET, 2), (Square.VINE_STREET, 1)]
```

Is there a simpl(ish) way to validate what the AI returns to me? I'm imagining something like this:

```
    instructions = player.sell_houses()
    if not typecheck(instructions, [(str, int)]):
        # Data was not valid...
```

I don't just want to check that the returned data is a list. I want to check that it is a list of a specific type. In the example, it is a list of tuples where each tuple holds a string and an integer.

I've seen that a lot of the Python type-checking questions get the answer "type checking is evil". If so, what should I be doing in this case? There doesn't seem to be anything stopping the AI code from returning absolutely anything, and I have to be able to validate or cope with it in some way.

---

Edit: I could check this 'by hand' by writing a function. For `instructions` above it could be something like this:

```
def is_valid(instructions):
    if not isinstance(instructions, list): return False
    for item in instructions:
        if not isinstance(item, tuple): return False
        if len(item) != 2: return False
        if not isinstance(item[0], str): return False
        if not isinstance(item[1], int): return False
    return True
```

But in this case, I would have to write a similarly complex validation function for each type of value I need to validate. So I'm wondering if a more generic validation function or library exists where I can give it an expression (like `[(str, int)]`) and it will validate against it without having to do the work by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. It looks from the answers so far that there may not be a library function that does this, so I've written one:

```
def is_iterable(object):
    '''
    Returns True if the object is iterable, False if it is not.
    '''
    try:
        i = iter(object)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def validate_type(object, type_or_prototype):
    '''
    Returns True if the object is of the type passed in.

    The type can be a straightforward type, such as int, list, or
    a class type. If so, we check that the object is an instance of
    the type.

    Alternatively the 'type' can be a prototype instance of a more
    complex type. For example:
    [int]                   a list of ints
    [(str, int)]            a list of (str, int) tuples
    {str: [(float, float)]} a dictionary of strings to lists of (float, float) tuples

    In these cases we recursively check the sub-items to see if they match
    the prototype.
    '''
    # If the type_or_prototype is a type, we can check directly against it...
    type_of_type = type(type_or_prototype)
    if type_of_type == type:
        return isinstance(object, type_or_prototype)

    # We have a prototype.

    # We check that the object is of the right type...
    if not isinstance(object, type_of_type):
        return False

    # We check each sub-item in object to see if it is of the right sub-type...
    if(isinstance(object, dict)):
        # The object is a dictionary, so we check that its items match
        # the prototype...
        prototype = type_or_prototype.popitem()
        for sub_item in object.items():
            if not validate_type(sub_item, prototype):
                return False

    elif(isinstance(object, tuple)):
        # For tuples, we check that each element of the tuple is
        # of the same type as each element the prototype...
        if len(object) != len(type_or_prototype):
            return False
        for i in range(len(object)):
            if not validate_type(object[i], type_or_prototype[i]):
                return False

    elif is_iterable(object):
        # The object is a non-dictionary collection such as a list or set.
        # For these, we check that all items in the object match the
        prototype = iter(type_or_prototype).__next__()
        for sub_item in object:
            if not validate_type(sub_item, prototype):
                return False

    else:
        # We don't know how to check this object...
        raise Exception("Can not validate this object")

    return True
```

You can use this like `isinstance` with simple types, e.g:

```
validate_type(3.4, float)
Out[1]: True
```

Or with more complex, embedded types:

```
list1 = [("hello", 2), ("world", 3)]
validate_type(list1, [(str, int)])
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: If anyone has a better version of this (which maybe copes with more types) or a library that does something similar, please let me know!

Comment: This is a great solution.. i don't understand why you even need to ask here :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `isinstance`:

```
isinstance(instruction, (str, int))
```

Which will return `True` if instruction is an instance of `str` or `int`.

To check it all, you can use the `all()` function:

```
all(isinstance(e[0], (str, int)) for e in instructions)
```

This will check if all of the first element of your tuples are an instance of `str` or `int`. Returns `False` if any of it is invalid.

Comment: I don't think that this does exactly what I want. For example, if `instructions` was passed back as a float then the code would throw an 'object is not iterable' exception. What I would like is a simple way to check: first that the result is a list; then that the items in it are tuples; then that the tuples have two elements; then that the first elements are strings; then that the second elements are ints. But all in one handy function call if possible!

Comment: I don't mind if the solution is not available directly in Python. If there is a library for this, then that would be great.

Comment: Meh, that's a lot. Seriously, i provided you an example on how to do it.. You just have to check it more times, don't you? Come on! :) You should be able to do this.

Comment: Hint: start with `if isinstance(instructions, list) and all(isinstance(e, tuple) for e in instructions)`. Wrap it in a function `is_valid`, which returns `True` or `False` depending on the input. Haha :)

Comment: Re: Meh... I don't want to sound ungrateful, and I'm very pleased that you've taken the time to answer my question! I think my question must have not been clear enough. I know that I could check through the types 'by hand'. I was hoping (maybe too much) that there would be a simple way to check for complex, nested types.

Comment: If you can show that you did it by hand, i'll give you a one liner :) Update your question!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42250/discussion-between-richard-shepherd-and-aikid)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the `type` function:

```
>>> type("abc") in [str, tuple]
True
```

Although aIKid's answer will do the same thing.